# Cannot mount SD card after hard shutdown

Tags: ext4, fsck, sd-card

I have an SD card in my raspberry PI, on which I pulled the power. Now, I cannot boot from it, or even read it from my (Fedora) laptop. When running `fsck` I get this error:

```
[bf@localhost ~]$ sudo fsck -V /dev/mmcblk0p2
fsck from util-linux 2.28.2
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/mmcblk0p2] fsck.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p2 
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 has unsupported feature(s): FEATURE_I17
e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!
```

It somehow sees some unsupported feature that blocks any usage of the card. Any other fs tool (`tunefs`, `debugfs`) come with the same error.

Comment: Looks like you might need to use a backup superblock - see the man page for `e2fsck -b`

Comment: I ended up re-imaging the disk. There was no critical data on it.